# Setting a start column to write data to excel with the help of pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I read 21th column in an excel file named first

```
df_slope = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\excel\first.xlsx', usecols = [21])
```

After that, I should have checked the elements of df_slope one by one and If there are in the required range, I should store them in another dataframe and write to another excel. There is a "for loop" in general that loops as number of elements in df_slope:

```
for index, row in df_slope.iterrows():
```

If it is in the range, add that element to "empty_list"

```
empty_list.append(df_slope.iloc[count][0])
```

Also, there will be other parameters like elevation etc. This empty_list should contain these values.
After all, the final empty_list should be written to an excel file in 2D Matrix format
Each column should contain one-step of the for a loop. Taking data part is correct and it works fine on the console, but while writing to excel all data is printing the 0th column. I want this: Print the first 6 terms to the 0th column, then print the other 6 to 1st column... It should continue until empty_list's all elements will be written.

Ex:
empty_list = [0, 32, -2961, 247, 1734, 22, 1, 33, -3757, 196, 1308, 23]
Output should be
[image]

Comment: change your dataframe

Comment: This list reads from an excel file(with for loop) and after excel finish, the list is assigned to dataframe. In which stage and how I can change dataframe? I'm really a beginner... @Johnny

Comment: I still don't understand what you want...